# Angular binding with a method is not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, two-way-binding

I m trying to create a fake time stamp for my list elements. It should look like "4m ago, 1h ago, etc.."
So far i could manage it but when the time stamp is on the list, its not dynamic. I mean it stays always like "4m ago" but not changing after a minute later like "5m ago". I dont quite understand that because i m using new Date().getTime(), so i expect it ll always function from current time.
Any ideas what i do wrong ?
Thanks !

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ph3dmv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
 getFakeTimestamp(winner: SlotWidgetRecentWinnerObject) {
    const fakeTime = new Date().getTime() - 60 * winner.fakeTime;
       return this.slotWidgetService.timeSince(fakeTime);

  }



timeSince(timeStamp) {
    let now = new Date();
    let secondsPast = (now.getTime() - timeStamp) / 1000;

    if (secondsPast < 60) {
      return parseInt(String(secondsPast)) + 's';
    }
    if (secondsPast < 3600) {
      return parseInt(String(secondsPast / 60)) + 'm';
    }
    if (secondsPast <= 86400) {
      return parseInt(String(secondsPast / 3600)) + 'h';
    }
  }
```

And html

```
 <ng-template #recent_winners>
    <div class="recent-winners__container">
        <div *ngFor="let winner of slotWidgetService.recentWinnersList; let i = index"
             class="recent-winners__item" (click)="play(winner.gameLink)" [@slideInOut]>
            <img [src]="winner.imageUrl" alt="{{ winner.gameName }}">
            <div class="block__container--first">
                <div class="block__container--first--gameName">{{winner.gameName}}</div>
                <div class="block__container--first--firstName">{{winner.firstName}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="block__container--second">
                <div class="block__container--second--timestamp">{{getFakeTimestamp(winner)}} ago</div>
                <div class="block__container--second--winning">{{winner.amount}} €</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because nothing is triggering change in your component

To do so update your code and add

```
 lastTime$: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lastTime$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(c => this.getFakeTimestamp()));
  }
```

Then in your template

```
<div>{{lastTime$ | async}}</div>
```

So this way every second fake timestamp will be triggered and will update view

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhlgjl?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

After you updated the question my answer will still apply

1. Create new component which will show you fake data and add @Input as winner
2. then in that component use subject with interval
3. In your code where you have iteration replace `<div class="block__container--second--timestamp">{{getFakeTimestamp(winner)}} ago</div>`  with `<div class="block__container--second--timestamp"><my-new-component [winner]="winner"></my-new-component></div>`

---

Looks like I misunderstood question or since I thought you have problem that date is not changing on UI

If you need to do logic where it shows when item was change then I would go with https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment#readme and then in code you can use smth like `Last updated: {{myDate | amTimeAgo}}`

Comment: Sorry i think i made a mistake. its actually a list element so this.lastTime$ wouldnt work because every list element has different timeStamp. I ll correct my question

Comment: @TolgaTamer You will need to use pipe for that

Comment: what should the pipe do ?

Comment: @TolgaTamer I've update answer a bit logic is still the same

Comment: thanks. But in your stackblitz the time is constantly changing. I need it to change exactly 1 min after 1 min passes.. like if it shows 4 min before, 1 min later it should show 5 min before.

Comment: @TolgaTamer well if you need once a minute that change interval to be 60000

Comment: yes but changing interval 60000 means that it ll trigger getFakeTimeStamp() every minute. And everytime it is triggered, it ll give different number. Use case is that 4m should be 5m after 1 minute. With what you suggest, it ll change the value 1 min. later but the value can be anything

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got your calculations right. Your fakeTime is always subracted from the current time wich results in always the same time difference:

```
getFakeTimestamp(winner: SlotWidgetRecentWinnerObject) {
const fakeTime = new Date().getTime() - 60 * winner.fakeTime; // fakeTime will always be winner.fakeTime minutes ago. new Date() returns the same as Date.now()
   return this.slotWidgetService.timeSince(fakeTime);
}
```

Another hint: there is this Library called `moment.js` which makes working with times and dates really easy. Also there is a angular pipe wrapper of it `ngx-moment` which I would prefer to do such tasks

Comment: Fake time is basically "this.fakeTime = this.randomBetween(1000, 100000);"

Comment: Ok. In your stackblitz you subtract that random number from the current time (lets say 5000). So the timestamp you get is 5000 (seconds?) behind the current time, which results in 1h ago. the next time the random number gets 5000 you will also see 1h ago, because its calculated based on the current timestamp